# Why does the first code works and second one not working?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Please explain why does the first code works and second one not working. What am i doing wrong?

**Code 1 (working code)**

```
test1 = (function() {
  var foo = 6;
  return function() {
     alert(foo);
  };
})();
test1();
```

**Code 2 (not working)**

```
function test1() {
  var foo = 6;
  return function() {
     alert(foo);
  };
};
test1();
```

Comment: Try `test1()()` in the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not invoking the returned function object, in the second case. You need to do

```
test1()();
```

You can check that like this

```
console.log(typeof test1());
# function
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, is there better way to do this than putting two brackets?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to assign a value to 'foo' inside the second function without returning it. `v = function () {
  var foo = 6;
  function() {
     foo = 4;
  };
  alert(foo);
};
v();'

Comment: But we are doing the same as in your first example. See the `})();`, we execute the function once and it returns a function. That is stored in `test1`. Again, you are executing that function. We are just doing it together in this case. Thats it.